# Convert base 10 into a certain base

Tags: c++, radix

I have a problem. 
I want to convert an integer (ex 64) into a certain base (ex 4). The number would look like 100 ( I think ). 
I need to get the number as presented before ( 100 ). 
If I use the algorithm I thought of I will get 001 which will be transformed into 1. How can I convert the base 10 integer into a base 4 representation starting with the first digit that is not 0. 
Sorry for my bad explanation, I hope somebody will understand.

```
int x=64;
int t=x; // temp variable
int pp=0;
int base=4;
while(t!=0)
{
        pp = pp * 10 + t%base;
        t/=base;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase

Comment: I assume you're doing this as an exercise, since there are libraries for base conversion. The base is a display property of a number, so I wouldn't store it in an `int`. You can run through your loop putting the characters into a `char` array, then display the `char` array in reverse order.

Comment: What the duped answer hasn't really made clear is that what you're doing doesn't really make sense. Numbers are effectively baseless - if I have 25 of something I always have the same number of them no matter what the base is. Infact your computer probably stores all numbers as base 2 internally but you dont see this. What makes a difference is _displaying_ that number to the user (or saving it in a file, etc). In that case, when you convert it to a string you need to specify the base for the conversion. Having an variable of type `int` in a specific base makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the data to the front of your value:

```
int x = 64;
int t = x; // temp variable

int pp = 0;
int base = 4;

int pos = 1;

while (t != 0)
{
    pp += (t % base) * pos;
    t /= base;
    pos *= 10;
}
```

I hope you only use this for playing around as there are a lot of traps you could fall in (e.g. if `base` is less than 0 or more than 10)

Comment: but this gives me 2101 when i put in 64 and 4 as a base, shouldn't it give me 100?

Comment: It gives me 1000, which is the correct result.  100 base 4 is 16 base 10.  I don't know how you got 2101.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that this code is **not** converting from base 10 to another base.  What it is doing is computing a number whose digits in base 10 are the same as the original number's digits would have been in the other base.  So if you do this conversion and then print in base 10, you will get the same output (subject to many constraints) as printing in the desired base would have produced.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I don't know how I got 2101 either...